# Android Studio 4.0: Killing Emulator Process

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.0

When I try to start my virtual device it gets killed instantly. I tried to change the graphics mode to software but nothing changed. Maybe its important to know that I use an AMD processor and there for not Intel HAMX.

I saw a fix which said that you have to change a setting at

"Menu -> Android Studio -> Preferences -> Tools -> Emulator
Uncheck Launch in a tool window option."

But I can't find that Emulator option

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with windows C++ tools. Install those and the problem will be resolved. https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe (or x86 version if needed). I tried everything else but this worked, thank you to Laxmi Chaitanya Kumar K. on Aug 5 '20 at 8:02

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors through SDK?
[image: Android SDK tools list - Hypervisor for AMD processors]

Comment: ok. Are you using Windows 10? If yes, have you tried to install WSL on your machine?

Comment: Didn´t fixed it

Comment: The issue is with windows C++ tools. Install those and the problem will be resolved.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019

Answer (score 0):

Newbie here but I wanted to learn more about developing apps, so I downloaded Android Studio to do an intro lesson and was frustrated by the same issue: the emulator was "killed" before opening.

Well, I think I saw a vague suggestion somewhere:

1. Uninstall Emulator using SDK Manager (SDK Manager > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools)
2. Reinstall the emulator from the SDK Manager

Voila! It worked for me. As a newbie you can imagine how cryptic this all was for me, but it's one way to learn, I guess!

Edit: also be sure to delete the previous AVD and make a new one, that seemed to work for me.